# Why Does This Return None when entering a list[0]?

Tags: python

'zipcodes.txt' is a text file with just zipcodes. The script works correct if I just enter a zipcode e.g. "90210". zip_list[0] type is a string and when printed it returns a single zipcode. However with the code as is a keep getting 'None'

```
from uszipcode import SearchEngine

search = SearchEngine(simple_zipcode=False)

zip_list = list(open("zipcodes.txt","r"))

search_by_zip = search.by_zipcode(zip_list[0])

print(search_by_zip.major_city)
```

Comment: have you checked what `zip_list[0]` actually is? e.g. `print(repr(zip_list[0]))`? I suspect it has a newline...

Comment: Yes. I meant to include that. It returns a zipcode. zipcodes.txt is literally a list of zip codes. Nothing else in the file. I've tried changing the index as well.

Answer (score 0):

I changed the variable names around a bit to make sense for me, but I had to `strip()` the list to get rid of the `'\n'`

```
first_list = list(open("zipcodes.txt","r"))
zip_list = []

for item in first_list:
    zip_list.append(item.strip())
```